# Rendering TIF image with JAI

Tags: java, tiff, jai

I'm trying to render a TIF file using the standard Java APIs, JAI and ImageIO:

```
RenderedOp op = JAI.create("fileload", new File("C:\\test.tif").getAbsolutePath());
```

or

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\test.tif"));
```

In both I get the fallowing error:

```
EOL code word encountered in White run.
```

I have the latest versions of jai_core, jai_codecs and jai_imageio on my classpath.

I tried to open the same image in other apps like The Gimp and Windows Image Viewer, and they can open it properly, although the bottom half appears to be missing.

Any idea what seems to be the problem?

Comment: I believe that the JAI libraries need to be installed first besides putting them into the classpath or importing their jars in the project. Did you do that?

Comment: It appears that your image is corrupt. If Windows displays only half and you're getting an error in JAI, then it's probably a corrupt image. Email me a copy of the image and I'll let you know what I find.

Answer (score 0):

After researching a few libraries (including native ones) I was able to render the TIF using the [JIMI Software Development Kit](http://java.sun.com/products/jimi/), which is a library from Oracle (Sun). In the page it is said that this toolkit is to be used on old Java platforms, but in my case it solved the problem.

Example code:

```
    JimiCanvas jCanvas = new JimiCanvas();
    jCanvas.setImagePath("C:\\test.tif");
    Image image = jCanvas.getImage();
```